# Как сделать такое же поле ввода коментариев?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Чтобы можно было изменять шрифт онлайн]

................................................................................

Comment: Я предлагаю сперва открыть инструменты разработчика и просмотреть код. Повторить. Если не получится, задать конкретные вопросы где произошёл затык.

Comment: Какое такое же вы имеете в виду?

Answer (score 0):

Это textarea с параметрами. Примерно так.

```css
#wmd-input {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="wmd-input"></textarea>
```